# How to toggle a boolean field for multiple records generating just one SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to write a migration to update a boolean field where the field will mean the exact opposite of what it means currently. Therefore I need to toggle every record to update the records where this field is `true` to `false` and vice-versa.

Example:

```
class ChangePostsVisibleToArchived < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    rename_column :posts, :visible, :archived

    # Toggle all tracked topics
    # What I DON'T want to do:
    Post.all.each { |post| post.toggle! :archived }
  end
end
```

The way I described above will generate one SQL command per Post record.
Is there a way I can toggle all records within a single SQL command using rails ActiveRecord syntax?

Comment: `UPDSTE  .... SET boolcol = NOT boolcol WHERE ....`

Comment: Yes @LaurenzAlbe, I can use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('UPDATE posts SET archived = NOT archived')` but I wonder if there's an alternative in Rails ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Post.update_all "archived = NOT archived"`